# iPad - Drafts folder mystery

Tags: ipad, exchange-activesync

iPad setup **Exchange sync**.

I create a draft email, then go to the **draft folder** and its there.

I then go back to the inbox on the iPad and after it syncs, I go back to the drafts folder and it loads up drafts from 2000-2013 but **does not contain my most recent draft**.

If I go to inbox and back to drafts a few times then it will display my draft again minus the drafts from 2000-2013.

I then bounce back and forth a few times and it will go back to the original draft again but never display them at the same time.

Also, some draft messages have gone into the abyss never to be found.  Any suggestions would be great.

Mark

Comment: Let's see if anyone has a ready answer. If not, we can help you edit your question to provide more details on what you've tried, what exactly you don't get. See the guides on [about] and [ask] if you don't get an answer and decide to edit your question. They are often helpful in refining / reframing your query.

Comment: Could you get in touch with the server admin for the Exchange server? Server logs might help debugging this issue.